# How to format individual DropDownlist Items (color, etc.) during onDataBinding event

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a basic DropDownList bound to a ObjectDataSource:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="objDataSource1" 
DataTextField="FieldName" DataValueField="FieldID" />
```

The DataTable from which it receives the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` values also returns some other interesting information about the records.  Say `Active = Y/N` for simplicity's sake.

What I'd like to do is to set the background-color property of the DropDownList Item based on that Active field in the DataSource results.  Further, I'd like to do this "in the same pass" as when the DropDownList is bound to the data.    So my guess is that it has to happen during OnDataBound.

Things I already know/tried:

1. I could go back and loop through the DropDownList items later.  But it would involve embedding loops and re-visiting the DataTable rows and it just seems inefficient

   ```
    int row;
    for (row = 0; row < DropDownList1.Items.Count - 1; row++)
    {
       [[if this row = that data row]]
        DropDownList1.Items[row].[[DoStuffHere, etc.]]
    }
   ```
2. We already do stuff like this with the GridView `OnRowDataBound` event, by accessing the `GridViewRowEventArg`s e.  What I seem to be missing is an `OnDropDownListItemBound` event, so to speak.

Hope I've been clear and concise.  Seems as though it should be easy...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can't do it during OnDataBinding because the data has not actually been bound yet.  Your best shot is (1), that is, use OnDataBound and loop through the items.

```
protected void DropDownList1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(ListItem myItem in DropDownList1.Items)
    {
         //Do some things to determine the color of the item
         //Set the item background-color like so:
         myItem.Attributes.Add("style","background-color:#111111");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Binding vs Bound correction.  Editing that.

I guess my question remains as to whether there's a way to handle each individual Item as it's bound, much as you can do with the individual rows of a Gridview.   

If no such thing presents itself, I'll get to loopin'

Comment: @LesterDove As far as I can tell from MSDN, there is no such thing as ItemDataBound for either the DropDownList control or the ListItemCollection class, which is the items held by the dropdownlist.

Comment: Thanks.  This being the case, I'll avoid binding the control altogether and just populate it programmatically so that I can make those conditional tweaks on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

I am using This code and it's working fine with me:

```
DropDownList1.Items(0).Attributes.CssStyle.Add("color", "Blue");
DropDownList1.Items(0).Attributes.CssStyle.Add("background-color", "#eae9e9");
```