# @Html.DropDownListFor; How to set different background color for each item in DDL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dropdownlistfor

I have a dropdown list (@html.DropDownListFor) wherein I am showing name of colors... I want to display each item having seperate background color.. Like, an item "Green" should be in green background, and "Yellow" in yellow background.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609344/how-to-format-individual-dropdownlist-items-color-etc-during-ondatabinding-e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See resolved solution here on ASP.NET Forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1871921.aspx/1?%20Html%20DropDownListFor%20How%20to%20set%20different%20background%20color%20for%20each%20item%20in%20DDL%20)

Comment: I've used the concept in this sample app: http://www.leniel.net/2013/02/data-binding-view-values-to-an-array-type-or-viewmodel-property-in-aspnet-mvc.html

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget that you can always write old fashioned HTML in a view (OMG!).

But, if you are using the code in multiple places, then write a helper that extends DropDownListFor to create your select with styling.  If you are using it once, you can simply write something like:

```
<select>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
    {
        <option style="background-color: @item.Color;" value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
    }
</select>
```