# ASP:DropDownList Codebehind Add Color

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, drop-down-menu

Dropdown list needs to display items with varying text colors.  Color is decided by server-side.  Uses `<style>` tags versus CSS styling sheet.  See example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListItem li = CreateListItemWithColor("Hello", "myValue", "blue");
        employeeDropDownBox.Items.Add(li);

    }
public ListItem CreateListItemWithColor(string text, string value, string color)
    {
        //Create the list item based on input text/value
        ListItem li = new ListItem();
        li.Text = text;
        li.Value = value;
        li.Attributes.Add("style", "color="+color);
        return li;
    }
```

From what I have read in other SO posts about formatting list item text, my general procedure seems close.  But my ListItem is always black.  What am I missing?

---

Abbreviated HTML:

```
<style>
    #employeeDropDownBox {
        height: 65px;
        width: 425px;
        font-size: 27px;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }

</style>

<div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="employeeDropDownBox" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't think individual `option` elements in a `select` even *could* be styled.  That's always been an issue in web development, since different hosts render `select` elements their own way.  Generally the solution has been to use JavaScript plugins to create custom elements which mimic the behavior of a `select` and synchronize with a hidden `select`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609344/how-to-format-individual-dropdownlist-items-color-etc-during-ondatabinding-e

Comment: @MehdiDehghani Extra css file is unnecessary.  I am modifying other ASP control attributes using the `<style>` tags successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adding `style`, add `css class` & use this `class` in your `css file` to handle the color

```
li.Attributes.Add("class", "blue"); // you can use the `color` parameter as well
```

In your css:

```
.blue {
    color: blue;
}
```

**Update**

So, you need to use `:` instead of `=`

```
    li.Attributes.Add("style", "color:" + color);
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue.  I specifically am using the <style> tag approach for other controls.  A css class is not the answer here.

Comment: If you use `css` for `styling`, your life will be easy in future, imagine maybe tomorrow your customer ask for another color, editing `css` is much easier than editing `C#`

Comment: I appreciate your perspective.  However I have a much larger application using `<style>` tags that I am modifying.  CSS style sheets are a consideration for future updates.

Comment: So, please tell me an example of generated `option tag`, use the browser's console